# Parse Php in Mysql output

Tags: php, mysql

i have a website with a Mysql database that has html in each row (yes, i know this is not ideal). The problem is that the programmer simply copied and pasted duplicated text in many rows. I therefore have to manually edit the html in many rows if i need to update the text. I wanted to includ a 'include' or 'require' function and store the generic html in an external file but it doesnt seem to parse in the mysql output (only shows the static html). Therefore, how can i include reference to an external file in the header html of the mysql rows that contains html? That is, i need to parse php included in a row of the mysql database and not from a php page calling to the database. I tried to the eval function but still it could not retrieve a external php file.

Another alternative is that the duplicated text is actually another row in the database. Therefore, i'm not sure how i can make a page dynamically pull multiple rows from the database in a specific order?

What a mess. Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: fix the overall design rather than try to patch this.

Comment: Thanks Dagon (hey are you the guy with the email script??). I use it on my site also. Its worked great for years now.

How can i redesign this with basic php knowledge. I dont have another programmer.

Comment: no, and have you considered an open source CMS

Comment: yes, i am using joomla. I can edit the html nicely in a WYSIWYG. However, i dont know how i can incorporate the include for the generic html in each row. Any ideas?

Comment: sounds like an issue with the template, you still shouldn't be putting php in the db

Comment: ok, but i actually have no other option. I am looking for a solution to the questions originally asked. I cant rewrite the website. If i could go back in time i'd have contracted a better programmer.

So are you saying it cant be done?

Answer (score 0):

You could parse each rows when getting them.

```
preg_match_all ("#include\((.+)\)#", $row, $result);
foreach ($result[1] as $value) {
    include ($value);
}
```

Or something like that. :)

( http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match-all.php )

Comment: Thanks, but this code does not work within a row of mysql. It wont parse

Comment: At least do you know that you can't execute code in anything mysql stores ? A string is a string, it will NEVER execute itself.
You have to parse before inserting it, or after getting it.
Like on my answer, you'll need to SELECT row FROM html_pages WHERE page='$page'; and then execute the code I gave you on $row = your_fetched_query['row'] and then do whatever ou wanna do with it. This is assuming you have put in your row "include('whatever_file_you_want_to_include')" .

Comment: ok. Looks like i need a new programmer then. This is beyond my abilities. I have four drop down boxes that a user starts with the first box, then the second is dynamically generated from the db. The user then selects a new item and the third box is generated. As the user is selecting the items in the drop down box, html from the db is shown below which details more of what they are selecting. There are a number of different combinations, hench the html of the first drop down is the same for many combinations as selected from the second box onwards.